# HTML5 Canvas display and drag images

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Basically I've created shapes image that are transparent in their inside, so that when another image would be displayed inside the transparent part.

I've successfully displayed the shapes but I'm not sure how to drag them around.
So I would like to click first the button then I only want to drag around the the pattern (and resize if possible)

Here's my code so far:

```js
function show()
{

 function shape(){

  if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) { 
      var canvas = document.getElementById('shape');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
    }
  }
  
  
  function pattern(){
  
   if (document.getElementById('pat1').checked) { 
      var canvas = document.getElementById('pattern');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw_LgFWAcL6RzFH4EApgo69TX7xx6iUyPqLANgi5qdJ6QL9CY';

    }

  if (document.getElementById('pat2').checked) {
      
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-geometric-pattern_23-2147508597.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg';
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pattern');
     var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var canvasOffset=$("#pattern").offset();
    var offsetX=canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY=canvasOffset.top;
    var canvasWidth=canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight=canvas.height;
    var isDragging=false;

    function handleMouseDown(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDragging=true;
    }

    function handleMouseUp(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      isDragging=false;
    }

    function handleMouseOut(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
    }

    function handleMouseMove(e){
      canMouseX=parseInt(e.clientX-offsetX);
      canMouseY=parseInt(e.clientY-offsetY);
      if(isDragging){
          ctx.clearRect(0,0,canvasWidth,canvasHeight);
          ctx.drawImage(img,canMouseX-128/2,canMouseY-120/2,128,120);
      }
    }

    $("#pattern").mousedown(function(e){handleMouseDown(e);});
    $("#pattern").mousemove(function(e){handleMouseMove(e);});
    $("#pattern").mouseup(function(e){handleMouseUp(e);});
    $("#pattern").mouseout(function(e){handleMouseOut(e);});

    }
  }
  shape();
  pattern();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Choose Shape:
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape" onchange="show()"/> Rectangle
<br>
Choose Pattern:
<input type="radio" id="pat1" name="pattern" onchange="show()"/> Green Wave
<input type="radio" id="pat2" name="pattern" onchange="show()"/> Gray Tiles

<br>
Display:

<canvas id="pattern" name="pattern" height="500px" width="500px" style="position:absolute; background: transparent; border-style: solid;"> </canvas>
<canvas id="shape" name="shape" height="500px" width="500px" style="position:absolute; background: transparent;"> </canvas>
```

Answer (score 0):

I dont quite understand your question...

but your code doesn't seem to work.

since `show()` only triggered when radio is change,

you shouldn't write your mouse event inside of it.

and you bind event on `#pattern` that is on lower layer than `#shape`,

which will never be accessed.

I tried to modify your code a lil bit,

you may check it out if it could make a little sense to you.

```js
function show() {

  function shape() {

    if (document.getElementById('shape2').checked) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('shape');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/512/33/33848.png';
    }
  }


  function pattern() {

    if (document.getElementById('pat1').checked) {
      var canvas = document.getElementById('pattern');
      var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTw_LgFWAcL6RzFH4EApgo69TX7xx6iUyPqLANgi5qdJ6QL9CY';

    }

    if (document.getElementById('pat2').checked) {

      var imageObj = new Image();
      imageObj.onload = function() {
        context.drawImage(imageObj, 0, 0);
      };
      imageObj.src = 'http://img.freepik.com/free-vector/abstract-geometric-pattern_23-2147508597.jpg?size=338&ext=jpg';
    }

    //you may want to move these variables outside
    var canvas = document.getElementById('pattern');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    var canvasOffset = $("#pattern").offset();
    var offsetX = canvasOffset.left;
    var offsetY = canvasOffset.top;
    var canvasWidth = canvas.width;
    var canvasHeight = canvas.height;
    var isDragging = false;

  }
  shape();
  pattern();
}

//you can try to achieve what you want for your mouse event here
$('#shape').on('mousedown mousemove mouseup mouseout', function() {})
  .on('mousedown', function() {
    console.log('down');
  })
  .on('mousemove', function() {
    console.log('move');
  })
  .on('mouseup', function() {
    console.log('up');
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    console.log('out');
  })


//I moved in-line functions to here
var radio = document.querySelectorAll('input');

for (var i = 0; i < radio.length; i++) {
  radio[i].onclick = show;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" id="shape2" name="shape" /> Rectangle
<br> Choose Pattern:
<input type="radio" id="pat1" name="pattern" /> Green Wave
<input type="radio" id="pat2" name="pattern" /> Gray Tiles

<br> Display:

<canvas id="pattern" name="pattern" height="500px" width="500px" style="position:absolute; background: transparent; border-style: solid;"> </canvas>
<canvas id="shape" name="shape" height="500px" width="500px" style="position:absolute; background: transparent;"> </canvas>
```

Comment: thanks, how do i apply this for me able to drag around the image of the pattern?